# How to scale a GUI picture and button location

Tags: java, jpanel, tooltip

Hello guys it's me again with another question. So I have this program and I basically did what it was supposed to do, but I'm not really implementing the idea of a scroll panel in the program which I should be, because the dimensions for the scroll panel is very large. I only made it large because that's the way I can have my invisible button there without it moving. How can I make my invisible button stay at a particular place of the image instead of layout if you understand what I'm saying? I want the button to stay at a certain point on the image, not on the layout so that If I move the scroll Panel dimensions, it moves with it. sorry If i am bad at explaining things here is my code. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TransitMap
{
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Presents a frame containing a scroll pane used to view a large
   //  map of the New York transit system.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("New York Transit Map");

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      //frame.setLayout(null);
      //frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 900));

      JPanel mainPane = new JPanel();
      mainPane.setLayout(null);
      mainPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1300,800));

      ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("fortress.jpg");
      JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image);

      JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(imageLabel);
      sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
      sp.setBounds(0, 0, 1300, 800);

      JButton button = new JButton("test");
      button.setBounds(640,360,50,50);
      button.setOpaque(false);
      button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
      button.setBorderPainted(false);
      button.setToolTipText("<html><img src=\"" +
             TransitMap.class.getResource("Bala_Hissar.jpg") +
             "\"> <br> This is the fortress ");
      mainPane.add(button);
      mainPane.add(sp);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPane);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

Comment: `mainPane.setLayout(null);` isn't going to help

Comment: Apply an appropriate layout manager to the label and add the button to the label